# Headers in non-C++ OOP Languages

Tags: c++, oop, header-files, design-by-contract

I have been wondering for a while, why non-C++ OOP languages (not sure if there are other some that uses headers) doesn't have header files?

Well, what concerns me the most is that in C++ I can code a class header, and sends it to my mate to compile other code against it, while I am happy coding the actual implementation of the class on my own pace.

How can this be achieved in languages that doesn't have headers? Or maybe, is there something I am missing in my understanding?

How can I make a class contract with other colleagues, so that both can code in their pace? Should I just do some mock class without any implementation for methods, just with mock returns, to satisfy this need or how?

Comment: Code against interfaces.

Comment: or abstract/virtual Superclasses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Header files are a legacy thing from the time compilers did not have the power necessary to compile all your source files without the hints from the developer.

Modern languages (and in fact C++ can do so, too) use interfaces or base classes to implement design-by-contract.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ are very old languages, created at a time when the compiler needed *advance declaration* of identifiers in order to do a compilation in one pass and minimal memory usage (which was a *major* performance consideration at the time). The main purpose of header files is to provide those declarations, so the compiler can faciliate the necessary stack frame setups, memory allocations, type checks etc. etc.

More recent languages revolve around "cleaner" language structures, and get the information that C/C++ needed headers for either by convention, inspection, deduction, or a combination of those, at the cost of some flexibility and performance. The former is not always needed, the latter largely irrelevant given the performance of the systems we use today...

As for the "class contract"... in C/C++, your library might define thousands of functions, and regardless which ones you declared in your "exported" header, *they are all accessible and can conceivably be called directly*. The same is true with more recent languages; basically, *documentation* took the place of *declaration* (i.e., making access of those functions "easy"), but they are all there to be called anyway.

So **technically** you didn't need C++ headers for "design by contract" either. You could just have told the customer to "declare `void foo( int )` and call that". Modern languages just removed the intermediary and point you to the docs right away. ;-)

Comment: I said "cleaner", not "superior". ;-)